# Table Update- Calculated Field

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to update a table from another table.

Table 1 and 2 are a 1 to many relationship based of 3 columns. ie T1 has ID, Goal, subgoal, and then T2 has the same 3 but also the person that each one is applied to.

example- there is ID Goal 1 subgoal 1 in T1

T2 has ID Goal 1 subgoal 1 and "Mary" AND ID Goal 1 subgoal 1 and "Jack"

.

T2 also has a percentage complete metric. I want to be able to average that percentage and enter it as a column in table 1.

ex: T2 has ID Goal 1 subgoal 1 and "Mary" and is at 25%

AND ID Goal 1 subgoal 1 and "Jack" and is at 75%

so for T1 I want it to show ID Goal 1 subgoal 1 and 50%

additionally, based on requirements, the percentage complete for table 2 will only ever by 0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%. (idk if this info is more or less helpful, but it could help with iif statements)

I know that updating a table based on a calculated field is technically not doable (because this is MS ACCESS), but I have had people pitch workarounds before, so any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is possible to update a table with calculated data, just can't run an UPDATE action using an aggregate query as source. Workarounds involve VBA and possibly temporary table. Unless there are extraordinary circumstances, really shouldn't save aggregate data anyway - if it can be calculated for an UPDATE action, it can be calculated when needed. Why duplicate Goal and Subgoal in T2? Just save T1 primary key ID into T2.

Comment: hi @June7 Thank you so much! Using that link provided I came up with:

Comment: `UPDATE Subgoals
SET Subgoals.[Percentage Complete] = DAvg("[Percentage Complete]", "[MASTER TABLE]", "[ID]='" & Subgoals.[ID] & "'" AND "[goal]='" & Subgoals.[goal] & "'" AND "[subgoal]='" & Subgoals.[subgoal] & "'")`

Comment: its saying its "updating it" but i can see that it is not making the updates to the table. Additionally, i checked T2 to make sure it is not backwards, and it is not.

Comment: If ID is a number field, don't use apostrophe delimiters. Also have extraneous pair of " marks around each AND.

Comment: hi @June7, thank you! your comment made me check my data types and i realized i was trying to link a "number" to "short text" it is now working!